# need help on simple probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to understand the question:

An urn contains $n$ red and $m$ blue balls. They are withdrawn one at a time until a total  of $r$($r \leq n$) red balls have been withdrawn. Find the probability that a total of $k$ balls are  withdrawn.

The solution is given as,
Sample Space: $${n+m\choose k-1} \times (n+m-k+1),$$
$$\text{Event$(k^{th}$ ball is $r^{th}$ red ball})= {n\choose r-1}\times{m\choose n-r}\times(n-r+1)$$

Two things confuse me,

1) I don't understand why the sample space is the to choose $k$ balls instead of to choose $r$ balls. This is because the restriction is that "until a total of $r$ red balls have been withdrawn". Since the sample space defines the number of total possible outcomes, I think this should be the case.

2) I also don't understand why the event is in the form of  "combination". I think the order of red and blue balls are important. And also, these red and blue balls should be distinguishable. So I don't see why they are using combination instead of permute them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can think about it as a "product of two probabilities", if that helps you.

In order that the $k$th ball will be the $r$th red ball, two events should occur: (a) there will be $r-1$ red balls in the first $k-1$ draws, and (b) the $k$th draw is red.

What is the probability for (a)? It involves (a1) choosing $r-1$ red balls out of the $n$ existing red balls and (a2) choosing $(k-1)-(r-1)$ blue balls out of the $m$ existing blue balls, and all of that should be divided by (a)'s sample space, which is (a') choosing $k-1$ balls out of $n+m$ balls. That gives us a total probability of
$$\frac{{n\choose r-1}{m\choose k-r}}{{n+m\choose k-1}}$$

What is the probability of (b)? It involves choosing one of the $n-(r-1)$ available red balls from the $n+m-(k-1)$ available balls. That gives us a probability of
$$\frac{n-r+1}{n+m-k+1}$$

Multiply the nominators to get your "Event" and multiply the denominators to get your "sample space".

Answer (score 0):

The count of events where you take a total of $k$ balls is the number of ways in which you can take $k-1$ in any order, and then taking a specific ball: the remaining red one.

For the second part, you want to count in how many ways you can take out $r-1$ reds, before finishing, and how many blues came out. First take $r-1$ from $n$ and $n-r$ from $m$. The remaining ball is to choose from from $n-(r-1)$.

Dividing, with given $m,n,r$, 
$$\mathbb{P}(K=k) = \frac{\text{ways of ending with exactly k}}{\text{ways of ending in total}}.$$